# wget works in command line but does not retrieve file in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, wget

I am trying to create a shell script that will collect weather model data daily.  I plan on using cron but I am testing my shell script before putting it in the CRON. I try my wget command on the command line and it works fine.  When trying it in the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

date_time=$(date +"%m%d%H%M")
FILE="gfs_wget_$date_time.txt"

file1="ftp://ftp.ncep.noaa.gov/pub/data/nccf/com/gfs/prod/gfs.2014011618/gfs.t18Z.pgrb2bf09"

wget -o $FILE "$file1"
```

the log file gives the following:

--2014-01-16 19:17:44--  ftp://ftp.ncep.noaa.gov/pub/data/nccf/com/gfs/prod/gfs.2014011618/gfs.t18Z.pgrb2bf09
           => `gfs.t18Z.pgrb2bf09'
Resolving ftp.ncep.noaa.gov... 140.90.101.180
Connecting to ftp.ncep.noaa.gov|140.90.101.180|:21... connected.
Logging in as anonymous ... Logged in!
==> SYST ... done.    ==> PWD ... done.
==> TYPE I ... done.  ==> CWD /pub/data/nccf/com/gfs/prod/gfs.2014011618 ... done.
==> SIZE gfs.t18Z.pgrb2bf09 ... done.
==> PASV ... done.    ==> RETR gfs.t18Z.pgrb2bf09 ... 
No such file`gfs.t18Z.pgrb2bf09'.

Any help would be great.

WGET version 1.11.4
Linux 2.6.18-348.18.1.e15PAE i686

Answer (score 3):

The file you specify does not exist on the server. A file with a very similar name does exist: it has a <kbd>z</kbd> (lower-case) instead of the <kbd>Z</kbd> (upper-case) you specify.

Comment: OMG...I'm such a  bonehead.  Thank you for not laying into me about a dumb question.  My apologies for wasting anyone's time that looked into this.